# Can I connect to an instance running in private subnet(in a VPC) from an another instance (not in VPC) using Iam Role or using another way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I have a old Instance(Not in any VPC) lets say INS1, used for monitoring purpose.
Now I create two instance in private subnet(in some new VPC) say INVPC1,INVPC2.

Now, Can I connect to INVPC1,INVPC2 using INS1,
Is it possible using IAM role ?
There there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it won't be possible.  IAM has nothing to do with it.  VPC are private networks that you can configure according to your needs to isolate your infrastructure components from each others (like you would do in a datacenter) or from other AWS customers' networks.

A private subnet in a VPC, is a subnet which has no route to the internet and only private (non routable) IP addresses.  So the EC2 instances started in these subnets have no possibilities to receive inbound connections from the public internet or the old non VPC EC2 instances.  They can initiate an outbound connection if your VPC is configured with a NAT gateway.

This is similar to your Home network setup.  Your wifi is private and is using non routable IP addresses (typically, in the range 192.168.0.0/24). These machines can not receive incoming connections from the Internet.  But these machines can initiate outbound connections (to navigate web sites or watch Netflix for example), by sending their connection request to a NAT Gateway : your ISP provided router / box.

I would suggest to save the whole configuration of your INS1 instances as an AMI and re-create a new instance, based on that AMI, in your new VPC to migrate your monitoring instance to the VPC.  To get started, in the console, right click on the instance and select Images => Create Image.